# Compare probabilities across binary classifiers

Tags: probability, classification

I have a large labeled dataset (about 70 labels) and I'm running into a couple of issues :

- Having a large number of classes compared to the variables, I won't be able to do a straightforward multiclass classification, which is why I thought of doing many binary classifications (whether or not an individual belongs to a class or not) and then see how I can compare probabilities. Is that the way to go or am I thinking about this the wrong way ?
- If I do the binary classifications, what do I have to do to be able to compare probabilities ? And do I necessarily have to train all binary models on the same dataset ?

Comment: Why a large number of classes would prohibit you from using multiclass classification and why multiple binary classifications would be the solution? Could you give us more details?

Comment: I won't be able to use a multiclass classification since the number of classes and the number of variable are about the same, which is why I thought of using many binary classifications, one for each of the 70 classes, and then compare probabilities across all models for each individual to determine in which class they belong

Comment: @SaadCherkaouiIkbal Do you have several datasets, all of the same "type"? If so, why don't you combine them? Also, how does the labeling of your training dataset look like? E.g., do all class labels occur?

Comment: @frank For the sake of the example, lets just say that I have one dataset only, composed of 100000 individuals and about 70 categories, with each categories being represented equally within the dataset.

Comment: In this case, there should be no problem, at least not in principle. What exactly goes wrong? What is the classification method you use? The method "one against the rest" is usually not advisable, it has several issues, e.g. the balancing problem.